# Запрос к telegram API не удался. Ошибка 404 (Colaboratory

Tags: python, telebot

```
import random
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("<token>")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Я бот, который позволяет играть в игру 'есть что-либо'. Чтобы начать игру, введите команду /play.")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['play'])
def play_game(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Окей, давайте начнем игру! Я буду генерировать случайные слова, а вы должны будете назвать что-либо, что связано с этим словом. Готовы?")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    word = random.choice(["животное", "город", "фрукт", "предмет"])
    bot.reply_to(message, f"Хорошо, ваше слово - {word}. Теперь введите что-либо, что связано с этим словом.")

bot.polling()
```